# applying two different textures to a plane

Tags: texturing

when we apply a texture to a plane it shows on both side. i know this is a single face. but i want to model a movie poster which is normally white on backside. i want to make it some part rolled up and loosly hanging from wall, so that some portion of its white blank backside shows. anyway to do that with a plane ?? or i have to make a very thin cube to do that?? cube doesn't look convincing as a movie poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *backface* properties, which mean the inner side of the face. With the proper node setting:

[image: backface node]